# Visual Studio 2017 Azure Cloud Quickstart ProjectTemplate Missing？

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-blob-storage

In Visual Studio 2015 ,there's a project templates for some azure service(etc:blob、storage:queue).

[image]

Now, I'm using Visual Studio 2017 enterprise ,i can't find the project template after intalled Azure SDK.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The quickstarts aren't included in the box in 2017 - you can find the latest here:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=storage-dotnet&type=&language

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cloud is the monicker for the entire suite of products. Are you looking for the Asp.Net Core template that will run in Azure? Click on .Net Core and choose Asp.Net Web and it will set up a quick start for you that already can be published to Azure. Or was there a specific kind of template are looking for that isn't Asp.Net Core?

Edit: It's possible VS 2017 Azure SDK didn't release console templates yet. Having said that, the templates you have show how to use the Azure Storage code in a .Net Core project. They are less boilerplate and more tutorial. You should create a test one, see how the code works, then create a normal, basic .Net Core Console project and re-implement the code how you want it. There is nothing special about a quick start template except some pre-included dependencies and sample code.

Comment: I'm looking for the azure storage example project template.
Not the Asp.Net Core template.
In VS2015 the project template get a console application with code,that guide me how write code for azure storage.

Comment: And the Asp.Net Core templates are the same. One has a web page and the other has text in a window on your screen. The Azure Storage code is the same for both.

Comment: These [templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) is for ARM only.  It looks like don't have any sample code that @kkman021 looking for.

Comment: You're right, I did that on my phone and it wasn't a good link. I edited and put an explanation in.